# How large are iAd banners on Retina Displays?

Tags: ios, iad, retina-display

A quick search gave me the following info about iAd banner sizes. But with retina devices such as the new iPad, is the height of an iAd double, ie. 132px?

"For iphone its height is 50 for potrait and 32 for landscape For ipad its height is 66 for potrait and 66 for landscape"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure iAd banners are the same size **in points** on retina devices, meaning they will occupy the same space on the screen but with higher pixel density. [This Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html) suggests this is true.

Answer (score 0):

The iAd Banner use a real size of your display and not the resolution (this inside a xcode) if you use a iAd Producer is better make your banner ever strong and good resolution.

In fact the iAd Banner have not a resolution but use the real dimension of display for example:

iPhone5 portrait is **320x586**, but the resolution of Retina is **640x1136px**, the dimension of iAd in this case is **320x50** and is the same on any display Large 320, same happen on iPad.

if you want you can learn more on developer apple, here you can find the instruction and samples code: [DeveloperApple iAd Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/)

Hope this help you to understand :)